# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following: . ; The symbol ";" was substituted for "END" to continue

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, compiler-errors

I wrote the following program:

```
create or replace procedure ADDPHONE(IDPELATH  in number,IDTHLEFWNO in number )
is
cursor cursor_number is select id_pelath  ,TelephoneNumber from PhoneNumbers
where id_pelath>2;
more_than_two_numbers exception;
begin
open cursor_number ;
fetch cursor_number into IDPELATH;
if id_pelath%FOUND then raise more_than_two_numbers
end if;
close cursor_number;
exception
when more_than_two_numbers then 
raise_application_error('Error');
END;
/
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:     . ; 
The symbol ";" was substituted for "END" to continue.
```

Could you help me to find the error?

Comment: Please don't SHOUT.

Comment: if id_pelath%FOUND then raise more_than_two_numbers ; <--- i see you missed semicolon

Comment: There are multiple issues in the program. The input parameters are never being used,why do you need them?Cursor is fetching into one variable however definition says two? What is your problem statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues in the procedure.

1. Input Parameters are never used in the body.
2. Cursor is declared to fetch two but FETCH statement is only fetching one.
3. Incorrect usage of raise_application_error,it requires two input arguments.

I have modified the code that should do the job,

```
 CREATE or REPLACE procedure ADDPHONE(IDPELATH  in number,IDTHLEFWNO in number)
is

    lv_cnt number(10):=0;
    more_than_two_numbers exception;

BEGIN 

    select COUNT(1) INTO lv_cnt 
    from PhoneNumbers
    where id_pelath  = IDPELATH
    and TelephoneNumber = IDTHLEFWNO;

    if (lv_cnt > 2) then 
        raise_application_error(-20001,'Error - More than two Numbers ');
    end if;

EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
           raise_application_error(-20002,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
    END ADDPHONE;


/
```

Comment: the point of this program is to create a procedure that it will show how many phones are inserted in one costumer and if there are more than 2 it will raise an exception and it will not allow you to add more .I want to do it with using cursor but i failed .I knew i had more issues but the programm show me only this .I am not really good with pl/sql ,i am still learning

Comment: Cursor is used to process more than single records. If i understood your requirement correctly, a cursor is not required.Did you try the program posted in the answer section? Is it not working?

Comment: If I delete the when statement at the end its working  ,i dont know why i have error when i put the "when"statement but it's fine, not a big lose I just delete the last part .As for the cursors I was just tring to experiment to see if I can write it like that .In any case thanks for the help and the advices

Comment: Modified the code now, i missed the EXCEPTION bit.Glad that it worked.